# Sorting nested ordered dictionary in Python

Tags: python, collections, sorteddictionary

My original dictionary contains values of the form :

```
[(0, {'T8': (0.3978349, 0), 'T9': (0.84942997, 0), 'T6': (1.1480641, 0), 'T7': (2.1811862, 0), 'T4': (2.016099, 0), 'T5': (1.5923926, 0), 'T2': (0.20877934, 0), 'T3': (-0.095536113, 0), 'T1': (0.89533514, 0), 'T10': (0.11839861, 0)}), 
 (11, {'T14': (-0.50686657, 0), 'T15': (-0.47247946, 0), 'T16': (-1.4296696, 0), 'T17': (-0.62257302, 0), 'T12': (0.61257166, 0), 'T13': (0.64874935, 0), 'T21': (-0.46329427, 0), 'T20': (-0.72244251, 0), 'T18': (-0.85425723, 0), 'T19': (-1.4788039, 0)})
 (22, {'T25': (1.0260065, 0), 'T29': (2.1339068, 0), 'T28': (0.85323471, 0), 'T30': (2.4555078, 0), 'T23': (3.5931432, 0), 'T26': (0.52051008, 0), 'T32': (4.1754069, 0), 'T24': (1.2143329, 0), 'T27': (3.6651597, 0), 'T31': (3.1280968, 0)})]
```

this is few rows from a file of `10k` identical rows. Initially since this dictionary was unordered, I sorted it using key by removing the leading `T` values, which now has in the sorted form of keys

`0 -> (values) 11-> (values) 22-> (values)`

In order to so I did,

```
 nd = {}
 for qid, dinfo in res_scores.items():  #res_scores is the original unsorted dictionary
     val = int(re.sub("\D", "", qid))
     nd[val] = dinfo

 sd = OrderedDict(sorted(nd.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

Now the output shown is excerpt from `sd`. Now I require to sort the values of keys , ie:

```
{'T8': (0.3978349, 0), 'T9': (0.84942997, 0), 'T6': (1.1480641, 0), 'T7': (2.1811862, 0), 'T4': (2.016099, 0), 'T5': (1.5923926, 0), 'T2': (0.20877934, 0), 'T3': (-0.095536113, 0), 'T1': (0.89533514, 0), 'T10': (0.11839861, 0)}
```

to this form by removing the preceding T values ->

```
{1 : (0.89533514, 0), 2: (0.20877934, 0), 3: (-0.095536113, 0), 4: (2.016099, 0), 5: (1.5923926, 0), 6: (1.1480641, 0), 7: (2.1811862, 0), 8: (0.3978349, 0), 9: (0.84942997, 0), 10: (0.11839861, 0) }
```

How do I approach here efficiently to sort the values of nested dictionary in Python? I tried few solutions from similar questions, however failed to resolve the issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear: you first say that the original dictionary (`res_scores`) contains values of some form, but then proceed to use keys of the dictionary (`qid`) which are not described, so it's impossible to validate the logic. Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which we can run and modify so it provides the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, you can try sorting your T values like this:

```
T_values = {
    "T8": (0.3978349, 0),
    "T9": (0.84942997, 0),
    "T6": (1.1480641, 0),
    "T7": (2.1811862, 0),
    "T4": (2.016099, 0),
    "T5": (1.5923926, 0),
    "T2": (0.20877934, 0),
    "T3": (-0.095536113, 0),
    "T1": (0.89533514, 0),
    "T10": (0.11839861, 0),
}

result = {int(k[1:]): v for k, v in sorted(T_values.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0][1:]))}

print(result)
# {1: (0.89533514, 0), 2: (0.20877934, 0), 3: (-0.095536113, 0), 4: (2.016099, 0), 5: (1.5923926, 0), 6: (1.1480641, 0), 7: (2.1811862, 0), 8: (0.3978349, 0), 9: (0.84942997, 0), 10: (0.11839861, 0)}
```

Additionally, if you are using **Python3.6+**, dictionaries maintain insertion order, so you don't *need* to use `OrderedDict`.

Otherwise, you can use `OrderedDict()` like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

OrderedDict((int(k[1:]), v) for k, v in sorted(T_values.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0][1:])))
# OrderedDict([(1, (0.89533514, 0)), (2, (0.20877934, 0)), (3, (-0.095536113, 0)), (4, (2.016099, 0)), (5, (1.5923926, 0)), (6, (1.1480641, 0)), (7, (2.1811862, 0)), (8, (0.3978349, 0)), (9, (0.84942997, 0)), (10, (0.11839861, 0))])
```

Comment: bro you are a genius, as cool as the real RoadRunner, that worked like a charm, now just one more doubt, how to access these values , i mean in the present sorted order, how to access these values with an index or so, say if I want to access [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] , how do I approach?

Comment: @OBX No problem. Concerning accessing the values, you would simply access `result[1]`, and you would get back `(0.89533514, 0)`.

Comment: Cool, but say if i want only `0.89533514`  ?

Comment: @OBX Simply do `result[1][0]`. Note that if the key is at risk of not existing, then using `result.get(1)[0]` is more reliable, since it returns `None` instead of raising `KeyError`.

Comment: Thanks a ton brother!